# iphone app emoticons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, emoticons

I have made an iphone application that allows users to send text messages for free to any mobile. I want to allow users to add emoticons into their message from standard set provided by me. What might be the best possible solution for this scenario? 
regards
ayaz Alavi

Comment: Just tell the users to enable Emoji...

Comment: It would require them to install other application like FrostySpace on their mobile phone. I need a general solution for every user which may or may not have emoji powered keyboard. 
The most appropriate solution might contain list of images and their replicas like :) is equivalent to smiley1.gif and :D is equivalent to smily2.gif. But that plain message will become mms if it contains images in it. Therefore needs a most feasible solution without external apps dependencies. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way is to use UTF8 codes which map to images on the users' phones.

However, unless the recipients of the text have configured/setup their phone to support these codes ala the [Emoji app of the day], they will see little square boxes.

If both the sender and the recipient have your application, then you can handle it directly, of course.

So basically, you are SOL.  There isn't anything you can do besides recommend your users install an emoji app.  Sorry.

Comment: iPhone users can see Emoji *without* any [Emoji app of the day]. The [Emoji app of the day] is only needed to activate the keyboard. Also, after that you can remove [Emoji app of the day].

Comment: My Wife's 3GS didn't see any emoji until an app was installed.  It only showed square boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this

```
NSString *comment = [comment stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":)" withString:@"\ue415"];
```

Find some emotions code here

[Here](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/)